# Obtaining c and b of a sine function given 4 points

Tags: trigonometry

With the coordinates $(1,90) (2,93), (3,87) (4,82)$

And the general formula:
$a\times sin⁡(bx-c)+d$

I found $a$

$a=\frac{y_{max}-y_{min}}{2}=\frac{93-82}{2}=5.5$

I found $d$

$d=\frac{y_{max}+y_{min}}{2}=\frac{93+82}{2}=87.5$

Comment: so, you have $y = 5.5\sin(bx-c)+87.5$. Can you go from this?

Comment: I dont know but i need to find b and c from y=5.5sin(bx−c)+87.5 .

Comment: For example, if you take the first point $(1,90)$, you have this equation:  $90 = 5.5\sin(b-c)+87.5$ and you will get $0.4545.. = \sin(b-c)$. Do you know about `arcsin`? If you do the same for the other points you can find $b,c$